# If list item has child list, add css style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navigation from a ul, see below:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Top Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Top Link 2</a></li>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#" >Sub Link 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>        
    <li><a href="#">Top Link 3</a></li>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#" >Sub Link 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I have my css, hiding the the sub link's "ul" unless hovering the parent "li". (Will not show unless asked, as this is not the issues)

I'm trying to use my JQuery to add a css style (margin-bottom:30px;) to the top level "li" only if it has a child "ul" nested in it. My JQuery is as below:

```
<script>
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {

    if ($("nav ul >li").children("ul li")) {
        $("nav ul >li").hover(function () {
            $("nav ul >li").css("margin-bottom", "30");
        });

    }
});
</script>
```

This does not appear to be working for me, can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Or can they provide a better solution to this approach?

Comment: I would also suggest looking at suckerfish menus. Allways try to avoid setting styles in javascript, instead use css. See http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Comment: You have an extra `</li>` closing tag which is changing your DOM tree.  As written, there is no `ul` that is a child of `li`.

Answer (score 0):

`.children` will always return an array, check `.length`

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
    if ($("nav ul >li").children("ul li").length > 0) {
        $("nav ul >li").hover(function () {
            $("nav ul >li").css("margin-bottom", "30");
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a little something like this :

```
$('li > ul').each(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass("your class");
});
```

This will select all uls that are children of li's and apply the class to the respectful li.

Comment: Well now where is code and where is explanation and there is no expl on why it dint work for OP. LOL. Nice to see people giving lectures when they dont do it right themselves.. :D

Comment: @PSL look closely _This will select all uls that are children of li's and apply the class to the respectful li._

Answer (score 0):

`.children()` method returns an object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript, apart from that if the condition is valuated to true, you are adding a listener to all the `li` elements not just those that have `ul` children, You can use `.has()` method which is a filtering method:

```
$("nav > ul > li").has('ul').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      $(this).css("margin-bottom", "30px");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).css("margin-bottom", "n");
    }
});
```

Or:

```
li.hovered {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

$("nav > ul > li").has('ul').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass('hovered', e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you do have an extra `</li>` in your question which i think is a typo..

```
<li><a href="#">Top Link 2</a></li>
                     //-------^^^^^here
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#" >Sub Link 1</a></li>
```

anyways you check check for length of children if present..

try this

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
if ($("nav ul >li").children().length > 0) {
    $("nav ul >li").hover(function () {
        $(this).css("margin-bottom", "30");
    });

}
});
```